# HTML5 video player is not working in ionic5 android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to create a video player with captions for web, Android and IOS. So I used HTML5 video player. It works fine in web but in android device this is not working.[image]

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="videoplayer-container>
  <video src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"  #videoPlayer (click)="toggleVideo() ></video>
</div>
```

**TS CODE**

```
  toggleVideo() {
    if (this.videoplayer.nativeElement.paused) { 
      this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
    } else {
      this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view app logs using Logcat in Android studio and remote device inspect in Chrome to check what the error is.